# Use theme on views created dynamically

Tags: android, android-theme

I created a few themes for my app and everything works as intended for the xml layouts.

I declared some resources in my attrs.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="themed_button" format="reference" />
    <attr name="button_text_color" format="color|reference" />
</resources>
```

Then I'm using those resources in my layouts

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/themed_button"
    android:textColor="?attr/button_text_color" />
```

finaly I defined a few styles:

```
<style name="Theme.green" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="themed_button">@drawable/themed_button_green</item>
    <item name="button_text_color">@color/button_text_color_white</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.red" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="themed_button">@drawable/themed_button_red</item>
    <item name="button_text_color">@color/button_text_color_white</item>
</style>
```

Now what I want is to apply the same style on Views created dnamically.
I have no clue on how to retrieve current theme  resources called 'button_text_color' for exemple. Looks like I should use obtainStyledAttributes but I failed to use it...

Comment: I think you can only add styles programmatically to TextViews, I don't think it is possible to add they style after the object has been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating dynamically those buttons by calling their contructor and then setting the theme, I will inflate a button layout where I already took care of the theme, then I will set the text and click behavior by code.
If you have a solution to apply the theme by code, please let me know